# Why does DateTime::diff return 0 days between these dates?

Tags: php, datetime

Consider the following test case:

```
$start = new DateTime("2011-02-25");
$end = new DateTime("2011-03-25");

$interval = $end->diff($start);


echo "INTERVAL = ".$interval->format("%d");  // Should give me the 
                                             // interval in days, right?
echo "START = ".$start->format("Y-m-d");
echo "END = ".$end->format("Y-m-d");
```

The result is:

```
INTERVAL = 0  <---------- WTF????
START = 2011-02-25
END = 2011-03-25
```

`diff()` seems to claim that the period between February 25th, 2011 and March 25, 2011 is 0 days!

I must be overlooking something. But **what?**

Comment: I also tried turning around the order: `$interval = $start->diff($end);` with the same result.

Comment: I'm surprised to be saying this to you, but please see example #3 in the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php :)

Comment: @deceze yeah, I get it now :) Although I'm still having trouble understanding what `d` is supposed to do then to be honest. Anyway, it works! (**Edit** now I understand: It's the difference in calendar days. Duh.)

Comment: `'%m month, %d days'` → `1 month, 0 days`

Comment: @deceze yeah, thanks! I'm slow today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you need to use format code `'a'`.  `d` is the number of days in the diff, not the net number of days.  in the dateinterval object, `days` is the corresponding field.  in your example, you will see `m = 1`

Comment: Arrgh. I didn't understand that. Thanks! (can accept in 5 minutes)

Comment: Looking at this problem for more than an hour... Thanks for the solution!